# Filter Products by Access Group

Tags: attributes, products, collection-filtering

I try (for a special site) to filter the product collection by access group.
The attribute is set in the backend by selecting one group or more, hence I have an array of the access group names available for the product.

How can I filter the collection, only leaving me with the products of the access group of the user accessing the site?

I get the current users group:

```
$roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$role = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($roleId)->getData('customer_group_code');
```

and then try to filter:

```
$item_set = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
        ->addAttributeToFilter('access_group',  array('in' => array($role)));
```

Somehow I realise my approach might be wrong... but I'm a bit stuck :(
Any ideas how to achieve this?

[EDIT:]
Here's the full code:

```
<?php

$_category = $this->getDownloadsCategory();
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

function getAccessGroupID($name){
    $data = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
    ->getAttribute('access_group')
    ->getSource()
    ->getOptionId($name);
    return $data;
}

function getItemsForCategory($catID){
    $roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    $role = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($roleId)->getData('customer_group_code');
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catID);
    $item_set = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('access_group',  array('finset' => $role))
        ->load();
    return $item_set;
}

function DrawTree($category) {
    $hlp = Mage::helper('vietload');
    foreach($category as $_category){
        $catId = $_category["entity_id"];
        $catName = $_category["name"];
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
        print '<li class="level0 level0 level-top parent">';
        print '<a href="'. $category->getUrl() .'">'. $catName .'</a>';
        $items = getItemsForCategory($catId);
        if($items->count()>0) {
            print '<ul>';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                //var_dump($item->getAttributeText('access_group'));
                print '<li class="level1"><a href="'. $hlp->getFullUrl($item) .'">'. $item->getName() .'</a></li>';
            }
            print '</ul>';
            print '<span class="head"><a href="javasript:void(0);"></a></span>';
        }
        print '</li>';
    }
}

?>

<div class="block block-verticalmenu">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__("Downloads");?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content"><div></div>
        <ul id="ma-accordion" class="accordion news_accordion">
            <?php DrawTree($_category); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you have thought  wrong?

Answer (score 1):

when calling `addAttributeToFilter('access_group',  array('in' => array($role)));` magento expects `access_group` to be one single value.
this translates to `WHERE access_group in (2,3,4)`.
But role is one single value and access group contains the multiple values.
What you need is `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(role, access_group)`.

For that use

```
addAttributeToFilter('access_group',  array('finset' => $role));
```

Comment: thx marius. I tried this, but it gives me zero results... even though I see that the product is assigned to several access groups and $role has the correct current user group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the  below code.

Use conditions like this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('field_1'), // columns
    array( // conditions
        array( // conditions for field_1
            array('in' => array('text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3')
        ),
    )
);
```

This will generate an SQL WHERE condition something like:

```
... WHERE (
         (field_1 IN ('text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3'))
    )
```

Hope you can understand the Syntax.